# GORM One-to-Many relationship without foreign keys

Tags: sql, grails, grails-orm

I've been trying for a while to understand how GORM works, and I think I've got it down.  However, I'm having a heck of a time getting my relationships correct.

Here is my database schema setup (2 tables):

**Table - Users**

```
userhash varchar(255)
firstname varchar(255)
lastname varchar(255)
```

**Table - Logs**

```
userhash varchar(255)
accessdate date
```

There are no foreign key and primary key constraints defined in the tables.  However, in the users table the userhash will be unique.  I didn't design it this way, but I have to use it like this.

Now for my Grails domain classes:

**Class - Users**

```
class Users {

    String userhash;
    String firstname;
    String lastname;

    static hasMany = [logs: Logs]

}
```

**Class - Logs**

```
class Logs {

    String userhash;
    Date accessdate;

    static belongsTo = Users;

}
```

In my controller, I do the following:

```
def user = Users.findByUserhash("nraboy");
println user.firstname;
println user.logs;
```

It prints out the correct firstname, but when I try to display the logs, it is null or empty.  Am I requesting the data incorrectly for child tables or am I missing something somewhere in the domain class design?

I've tried to do the following, but had now luck as well:

**Class - Logs**

```
static mapping = {
    id generator: "assigned", name: "userhash", type: "string"
}
```

**Class - Users**

```
static mapping = {
    userhash generator: "foreign"
}
```

I figured the above would let me manually define the primary key and foreign key via code since it didn't exist int he tables.  No luck though.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have to do something with in Users for the logs association to force the foreign key to be in the Logs table, as it is.  See the [GORM docs](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/GORM.html#tableAndColumnNames) One-to-Many Mapping section.  Perhaps something like:

```
static hasMany = [logs: Logs]

static mapping = {
    logs column: 'userhash'
}
```

I would be curious to hear if this worked...

Comment: Hi, when I do that I end up with the following type of error: Unsuccessful alter table users_logs add constraint FK6F4170C73EC8C10A foreign key (userhash) references users

Comment: Hmmm... Are you sure that your data are consistent?  Are all the 'userhash' values in the logs table valid?  Are the no null values?

Comment: The data does match up.  No null values.  Could there be a problem with my id field?  My tables do not have id columns so I had to map the id property to userhash in Users.  Not sure what to map it to in Logs since it's more composite (neither userhash and accessdate are unique on their own).  Any recommendations would be appreciated.  Thanks,